# Accessing JSON object in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am making a trivia game with JSON, and I am stuck. First off, I can pull my data from JSON and get it to display in a list after working through the documentation, like so:

```
$.getJSON('/trivia.json', function(data) {
    var items = [] 
    $.each(data, function (item, i) {
        items.push('<li id="' + i.order + '">' + i.question + ' - ' + i.choices + i.correct +  '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('#example');

});
```

That works fine at creating a list of the questions and answers, so I can confirm I am calling the local JSON file correctly.

My next step is to get the question and answer data to be stored in my Javascript variable for the quiz to wrok. When I made the example quiz, I store the data like so:

```
var quiz = [
    {
        "question" : "Q1: Who came up with the theory of relativity?",
        "choices" : [
                                "Sir Isaac Newton",
                                "Nicolaus Copernicus",
                                "Albert Einstein",
                                "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
                            ],
        "correct" : "Albert Einstein",
    }];
```

I don't want the questions to be static, so I want JSON to take over supplying the question and choices.

I have tried to call the appendTo function for the quiz var, but it isn't passing the data through like it was when I created a list. Any ideas on how I can get the question, choices, and correct data sets to apply with the var quiz?

Comment: Isn't that just the value of `data` that's returned by `$.getJSON`? BTW, you need to iterate over `i.choices`, it's not a string that you can concatenate.

Comment: Mmmh, `var quiz = data;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may update your code to add the grapped data from Ajax request to **quiz** variable and iterate over choices to print them like the following code:

```
var quiz = [
    {
        "question" : "Q1: Who came up with the theory of relativity?",
        "choices" : [
                                "Sir Isaac Newton",
                                "Nicolaus Copernicus",
                                "Albert Einstein",
                                "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
                            ],
        "correct" : "Albert Einstein",
    }];     
$.getJSON('/trivia.json', function(data) {
    var items = [] 
    $.each(data, function (item, i) {
        var q = {"question": i.question, "correct": i.correct, "choices": []};
        var choicesStr = ""; 
        $.each(i.choices, function (it, choice) {
            choicesStr += "<span>choice</span></br>";
            q.choices.push(choice);
        }
        quiz.push(q);
        items.push('<li id="' + i.order + '">' + i.question + ' - ' + choicesStr  + i.correct +  '</li>');

    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('#example');

});
```